# What is the Basemap equivalent of Matplotlib's "ax1.add_collection(mylinecollection)"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am pulling latitudes/longitudes from a relational database. The points are vertices of line segments, and the database table is organized such that the points can be grouped based on a line number and ordered based on a point order number. Specifically, the database table has the following fields: latitude, longitude, line_number, pt_order_number.

I've pulled all of the line segments into a Line Collection. It plots as expected using Matplotlib `ax1.add_collection(mylinecollection)`. Note that I used line collections instead of an `ax1.plot(long,lat)` loop because some datasets have thousands of lines and tens-of-thousands of points (line collection is much faster and cleaner).

However, I need to plot these line collections using Basemap (so that I have a nice shaded relief and scale bar). Basemap cannot pass `.add_collection()`, and I am not sure what the alternative is. I could not find the answer or an obvious alternate approach in the Basemap Tutorials (but perhaps I missed it). Thanks for any help.

Current Code:

```
# note linecollection variable produced in function; performs as expected with "ax1.add_collection(linecollection)"
latitude_range = [34.012965603200001, 34.721878621999998]
longitude_range = [-116.76151759999999, -116.33691841200002]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

south, north = latitude_range[0], latitude_range[1]
west, east = longitude_range[0], longitude_range[1]
center = [(east+west)/2, (north+south)/2]

m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=west, llcrnrlat=south, urcrnrlon=east, urcrnrlat=north,
            resolution='c', epsg=4326,
            lon_0=center[0], lat_0=center[1])

m.arcgisimage(service = "World_Shaded_Relief", xpixels = 2000)
m.add_collection(linecollection) # throws error "AttributeError: 'Basemap' object has no attribute 'add_collection'"

plt.show()
```

Comment: Basemap uses an axes. `fig, ax = plt.subplots(); m = Basemap(..., ax=ax)` on this axes you can call any method you like, `ax.add_collection(...)`. Make sure the coordinates of the line collection are transformed to the basemap units first.

Comment: wow, how did I miss that--thanks very much, that works perfectly

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest If this is not a duplicate, I think it would be worth an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing the comment above as answer:

Basemap uses an axes:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
m = Basemap(..., ax=ax)
```

on this axes you can call any method you like, e.g.

```
ax.add_collection(...)
```

Make sure the coordinates of the line collection are transformed to the basemap units first.